# Marker event.listener iteration issue, Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

What I am trying to do here. When I press the marker. It should send me to the that id's page. It sending me to id's page. But it doesn't matter which marker I click I always going to same id's page. Listener is not working properly... I guess...

This is the full map:

```
  var estates = <?php echo json_encode($estates);?>;

  function initMap()
  {
      var options =
          {
              zoom : 6,
              center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
          };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
      @foreach ($estates as $est)
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
                url: "/pages/{{$est->id}}",
                label: {
                    text: estates.data[0].price.substring(0, 5),
                    color: "#fff",
                },
                position: {
                    lat: {{$est->lat}},
                    lng: {{$est->lng}}
                }
            });

           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
           window.location.href = marker.url;
         });
      @endforeach
  }
```

Any idea to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    window.location.href = this.url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that `window.location.href = marker.url;` lack of `[i]` of `marker`

Comment: nope, that's not the problem. I tried to add it too, `marker[i].url` no effects...